# What does it mean? 'pulling it low over her face'

Tags: verbs, literature

"She walked out the kitchen into the living room and picked up one of Michael’s baseball caps that he’d left on the sofa, before pulling it low over her face."

Can you give a description of an action that is expressed with 'pulling it low over her face"?

Comment: This means: "she pulled the cap downward so that it covered part of her face"

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes caps are so big that you can pull them lower to your eyes.  Many times baseball players do this to block the sun. It could also be that the cap is very big and she's lowering it over her face.

Also, you see people do this in movies to obscure their face from others.

Answer (score 1):

**A picture is worth a thousand words!**

[image]